# Correct transition config for click / touch drag transition speed in fancybox-3

Tags: transition, swipe, fancybox-3

fancybox3 transitionDuration config does not seem to affect click / touch drag transition speed which is always very fast. Does anyone know how can i control this click / touch drag transition speed please?

Comment: Sorry, there is currently no such option. You could edit js file (find `speedX = 300`), but that is not advised. So, you would prefer to lower that speed?

Comment: This content will be displayed on screen sizes from mobile up to 90 inch touch screen. I'd like to dynamically modify the speeds based on screen size e.g. if stood in front of a 90" screen you don't want a 300ms animation. Thanks for the heads up on speedX, that'll do it for now.

Comment: Interesting point, thanks for sharing!